# Get-Member for Cmdlets

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I`m new to PowerShell and was looking for a way to retrieve the properties of an object. I read up on Get-Member. 
However, when I tried to get the properties for an object "created" by the SharePoint Online cmdlet (Remove-SPOSitGroup) I get an error message:

```
"get-member : you must specify an object for the get-member cmdlet"
```

Moreover, in order to be even able to pipe the cmdlet to Get-Member I have to specify the required parameters "site" and "identity" for the cmdlet.

This in turn executes the command and deletes a SharePoint group.
I don`t want that. I just want to get the properties of the object that Remove-SPOSitGroup produces.

Here`s my command:

```
Remove-SPOSiteGroup -Site XXX -Identity XXX | Get-Member -MemberType Property
```

This works fine with

```
Get-Command | Get-Member -MemberType Property
```

As I mentioned this is new to me so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove-SPOSiteGroup doesn't have a return type, so won't pass anything to the pipe. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fp161373.aspx

Comment: Thanks. However, Get-SPOSiteGroup (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161385.aspx) does not have a return type either but 

Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site XXX | Get-Member -MemberType Property

works in this instance. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue what you are having is because you command is not giving any output:

**Remove-SPOSiteGroup**'s output will pass as an Input to the next cmdlet if you are piping it. Thats what Pipe symbolizes in PS.

So, in your case the return type is nothing as a result, the next cmdlet which is **Get-Member** is not getting any object to give you the details of methods & properties. Hope you are clear now about *get-member*

Comment: Thanks but please help me understand. By using

Remove-SPOSiteGroup -Site XXX -Identity XXX | Get-Member -MemberType Property

I am piping it to Get-Member.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo: Actually, `Remove-SPOSiteGroup` doesn't have any return type as an object , so it wont be able to parse to the next one. See the technet link for the return type: [Technet Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161373.aspx). The cmdlet or the function or the script should have an object to hold some attributes , methods or properties. In this case, its not there.

Comment: Thanks. Mathias R. Jessen mentioned the same reason above. But I mentioned that Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site XXX | Get-Member -MemberType Property works but does not have a return type either.
Please help me understand.